# SQL Server 2008: update query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have `TableA` with `FKColumnID`

I also have `TableB` with `ColumnID` and `ColumnName`

How can I update `TableA.FKColumnID` to have the same value as `tableB.ColumnName`?

```
Update TableA
Set TableA.ColumnName = TableB.ColumnName
```

Comment: How are the two tables related? You've only told us one column in TableA? Presumably you need one to join on and a different one to update?

Comment: A.FKColumnID and B.ColumnID are Identical

Comment: But once you do `SET TableA.FKColumnID = TableB.ColumnName` they won't be any more. (Edit: @William - Did you edit your question?!)

Comment: Yes I edited in teh grey area

Comment: Ah good. Just checking I wasn't hallucinating earlier.

Comment: I don't get why people come around and down vote questions...I was up to 3 upvotes but i guess someone was having a bad day...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
UPDATE TableA
SET ColumnName = TableB.ColumnName
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB on TableA.FKColumnID = TableB.ColumnID
WHERE < any additional criteria >
```

Comment: do you mean _SET TableA.ColumnName = TableB.ColumnName_

Comment: @William, yes.  The "TableA" element is not required because the UPDATE clause indicates the table where the SET clause applies.

Comment: Also, Would i not have to do an inner join to get all the rows?

Comment: @William, the INNER keyword is also optional in TSQL.  So, this is an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @bobs TSQL? How do I know if I am doing SQL or TSQL?

Comment: @William, if you are using SQL Server, then you are using TSQL, which is an extension (or variation) of the SQL standard.  So, in SQL Server, you are using TSQL and the INNER keyword is optional.